# AEM - how to prevent administrators creating users

Tags: aem

I trying to limit administrator users to create additional users or groups.
I've tried to achieve this by setting deny on rep:usermanagement and add child node for /home/users and /home/groups but users can still be created.

Thank you,

Comment: I'd ask, why would you want to do that? If you have a group of users who are not supposed to be admins, create a special group for them and permission it appropriately. You should never need to change the admin group/user permissions.

Comment: I've already created a group that doesn't have permissions on the /home folder and it does its job. 
I was just thinking about a more elegant solution.